# How to install Parity on Ubuntu?

Tags: parity, ubuntu, installation, enode

I am new in Linux Ubuntu and I want to install Parity UI to add an enode. For this, I need to install Parity on Ubuntu. Is there any commands for this? And where can I download its executable file?

Answer (score 7):

The [Parity](https://github.com/paritytech/parity) page has a one-line install command provided:

```
bash <(curl https://get.parity.io -Lk) -r stable
```

Answer (score 1):

parity is available using snap `sudo snap install parity`