# 'curl: no URL specified!' Installing Parity on AWS (Ubuntu)

Tags: parity, nodes, ubuntu, aws

The accepted answer found here does not seem to work for me:  https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/46926/11266

I created an EC2 instance of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (HVM)

```
$ bash <(curl https://get.parity.io -Lk) -r stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   170    0   170    0     0   1465      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1452
100  3847  100  3847    0     0  21491      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 21491
Release selected is: stable
Upgrading parity from 0.0.0 to 1.11.10
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
/usr/bin/sha256sum: /tmp/tmp.NnKCndYjTQ/parity: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/tmp/tmp.NnKCndYjTQ/parity': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/tmp/tmp.NnKCndYjTQ/*': No such file or directory
```

I tried wrapping the url in quotes, but I'm getting the same result.

```
$ bash <(curl 'https://get.parity.io' -Lk) -r stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   170    0   170    0     0   1360      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1349
100  3847  100  3847    0     0  21857      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 21857
Release selected is: stable
Upgrading parity from 0.0.0 to 1.11.10
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
/usr/bin/sha256sum: /tmp/tmp.VZclpPZSN8/parity: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/tmp/tmp.VZclpPZSN8/parity': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/tmp/tmp.VZclpPZSN8/*': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the one line command, but rather with the installer itself. You can see it by running:

```
 curl https://get.parity.io -Lk > installer.sh
```

to download the file and then by running

```
 ./installer.sh
```

You will get the exact same problem. The problem is related to the fact that the [website from which it gets the URLs to download the binaries](https://vanity-service.parity.io/parity-binaries?format=markdown) has changed the name for the stable and beta releases. So, you have to overwrite some variables in the bash file. From this

```
if [ "$RELEASE" = "beta" ]; then
    LOOKUP_URL="$VANITY_SERVICE_URL&os=$PKG&version=beta-release"
elif [ "$RELEASE" = "stable" ]; then
    LOOKUP_URL="$VANITY_SERVICE_URL&os=$PKG&version=stable-release"
else
    LOOKUP_URL="$VANITY_SERVICE_URL&os=$PKG&version=$RELEASE"
fi
```

To this:

```
if [ "$RELEASE" = "beta" ]; then
    LOOKUP_URL="$VANITY_SERVICE_URL&os=$PKG&version=beta"
elif [ "$RELEASE" = "stable" ]; then
    LOOKUP_URL="$VANITY_SERVICE_URL&os=$PKG&version=stable-backup"
else
    LOOKUP_URL="$VANITY_SERVICE_URL&os=$PKG&version=$RELEASE"
fi
```

Comment: I did not notice that, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Did you try the fix?

Comment: Not yet, I will today

Comment: That worked!!!!

Comment: It seems like someone fixed the issue.  The installer I just downloaded for another node works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use

```
bash <(curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ethcore/scripts/master/install-deps.sh -L)
```

This will install and configure the Parity client for you.